# Hash passwords in C# just like in CakePHP

Tags: c#, cakephp, cakephp-3.0, password-encryption

This wasn't probably the best title for this question but I'm going to explain it now.

Basically I made a website with **CakePHP** that hashes the user's password using **DefaultPasswordHasher** when they register and log in.

This is the code I used to hash the password:

```
protected function _setPassword($password)
{
    return (new DefaultPasswordHasher)->hash($password);
}
```

After that I decided to create a software with **C#** that requires the user to log in.

The program uses the same database as the CakePHP website, meaning that to verify if the password input into the password textbox matches the password in the database I must hash it using the same encryption that `DefaultPasswordHasher` uses. The problem is that I don't know what type of encryption `DefaultPasswordHasher` is based on, nor how to hash the password input into the textbox in C#.

Thank you for helping me :)

Comment: Do you need the passwords to be hashed exactly the same way? I don't know what algorithm CakePHP uses, but you may want to have a look at `System.Security.Cryptography.SHA256CryptoServiceProvider`

Comment: I don't think the password needs to be hashed exacly the same way. As long as I'm able to authenticate users in the C# program using the passwords that were created with DefaultPasswordHasher it's all good.

Comment: Why not create an API in your CakePHP project and perform the hashing there? I mean, it's very difficult to create the same algorithm unless you know exactly what it uses.

Comment: Humm that's a good sugestion. I think I'm going to investigate a little bit more about it. Thank you :)

Comment: If you want to know what CakePHP does, just look at [**the source**](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/3.4.2/src/Auth/DefaultPasswordHasher.php), the default password hasher uses PHPs [**`password_hash()`**](http://php.net/password_hash) with the `PASSWORD_DEFAULT` algorithm, which currently is bcrypt.

Comment: Oh thank you very much, I'll try that method!